# Procedimiento almacenado con un parametro para buscar coincidencia mientras se escribe Mysql

Tags: mysql

amigos saben como puedo hacer un procedimiento almacenado usando like que recibe un parametro, donde cuando pongo digamos pongo la letra "a", que busque todas las que comienzan con esa letra

```js
create procedure sp_busca_albun(
in nombres varchar(200)
)
begin
select idalbum,nombrealbum,fotoalbum,nombreartista from 
tb_album as tal inner join tb_artista as tar
on tal.idartista=tar.idartista
where  tal.nombrealbum like '%' + nombres + '%' and tal.tipo='FREE';
END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

Al utilizar el carácter comodín tanto al principio como al final, va a obtener todos los resultados en los que el campo "nombrealbum" contenga el carácter que buscas, es decir (con una "a"):

- hol**a**
- **a**dios
- s**a**ludo

Si quieres que obtenga sólo aquellos resultados que comiencen por "a" deberías poner en la condición del like:

```
like nombres + '%'
```